# Can't define variable with args as context

Tags: c#, .net, windows, variables

Title explained it, I'm new to C# and .NET, I'm passing 4 arguments through the program. 
But when I trying to define another variable with args as context but it is always null for some reason.

Arguments: "cmd.exe /K echo hi"
What did I try:

```
var var1 = args;
var var2 = args.Skip(1).ToString();
System.Console.WriteLine(var1);
System.Console.WriteLine(var2);
```

Excepted:

```
Shell> myProgram.exe cmd.exe /K echo hi
cmd.exe /K echo hi
/K echo hi
Shell>
```

Result:

```
Shell> myProgram.exe cmd.exe /K echo hi
      # <- nothing here

Shell>
```

After that, I tried read the variables in visual studio 2022, they are null, either. Photo below:
[image: photo]

Full code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sudo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void sudo_start(string file, string argument)
        {
            Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ".";
            startInfo.FileName = @file;
            startInfo.Arguments = @argument;
            //@"/C computerdefaults.exe"
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
        }
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int var;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                var var1 = args;
                var var2 = args.Skip(1).ToString();
                System.Console.WriteLine(var1);
                System.Console.WriteLine(var2);
                //string argument = string.Join(" ", delFirst);
                //sudo_start(args[0], argument);
                var = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(@"Error: No arguments given! example: sudo cmd.exe");
                var = 1;
            }
            return var;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't include tags in the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: *"Title explained it"*. No it didn't. Instead of telling us that the title explained it, whether it did or not, just explain it. You only need to include the facts of the problem in your question. Whether or not you're new to anything isn't really relevant either.

Comment: I honestly would have expected this to not compile, but anyhow: can you try and rename `int var;` to something else then try again?

Comment: I just tested your code in the debugger and did not see the behaviour you report. I see `var1` as an array with exactly the same elements as `args`, which is exactly what you'd expect because it's the same array. As for `var2`, it has the value "System.Linq.Enumerable+<SkipIterator>d__31`1[System.String]", which is probably not what you intended but is definitely what that code is doing. If you want to debug a project with commandline arguments, enter those arguments on the Debug page of the project properties and then run as normal in the debugger.

Comment: @Fildor, I thought that too and had to test for myself, but it is legal. Not sure why `var` is not treated like other keywords. Maybe it's because it might already have been used a lot as an identifier and they didn't want to break existing code.

Comment: Possible, yes. But still surprising. This behavior though seems not reproducible?

Comment: Hmm I have no idea what's going on, but I'll record about this

Comment: Okay, something weird is going on, my pc bsoded during I recording, after that it works again(with exactly settings, config etc.) I re-opened the ide and tried debugging it again now it works. Sorry for wasting you guys' time, I really have no idea.

Comment: @jmcilhinney `var` is a "contextual keyword" which means it is not a reserved word but has meaning depending on context, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Answer (score 0):

Restart fixed this for some reason. 
More detail at comment.